A question on the proof of the ratio limit theorem for Brownian motions.
I am trying the prove the following ratio limit theorem, and I think I got it but I am not entirely sure that the mathematical logic in the last part of the proof is correct, and so I am asking if anyone could verify the steps. The theorem is stated in the lecture notes an introduction to stochastic processes in continuous time and is stated as theorem 3.4.4 on page 91.
As a quick note: the proof uses some results from earlier results from the lecture notes, most notably lemma 3.4.3 (iii).
Theorem 1.1 (Ratio limit theorem) Let $f,g$ be $\lambda$-integrable functions with $\lambda(g)>0$, then
\begin{equation}
    \lim_{T\to\infty}\frac{\int_0^Tf(W_t)\mathrm{d}t}{\int_0^Tg(W_t)\mathrm{d}t}=\frac{\lambda(f)}{\lambda(g)}\quad\text{a.s.}
\end{equation}
for $\lambda(f)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)\mathrm{d}\lambda(x)$.
Proof: Write $X_t=W_t+X_0$ where $X_0$ is an integrable random variable independent of $W_t$ for all $t\geq 0$ with initial distribution $\nu=\delta_x$ for some $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Put $\tau_1^1=\tau_1=\inf\{t\geq 0:X_t=0\}$, $\tau_0^1=\tau_0=\inf\{t>0:X_t=0,t\geq\tau_1\}$ and for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, let $\tau_0^n=\inf\{t\geq \tau_1^n:X_t=0\}$ for $\tau_1^n=\inf\{t\geq\tau_0^{n-1}:X_t=1\}$. Let $A\in\mathcal{B}$ and $f\in L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ be so that $f(x)={1}_A(x)$, then
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        \mathbb{E}_0\int_0^{\tau_0^1}f(X_t)\mathrm{d}t=\mathbb{E}_0\int_{\mathbb{R}}{1}_{A}(X_t){1}_{[\tau_0^1,\infty]}(t)\mathrm{d}\lambda(t)=2\int_{\mathbb{R}}{1}_A(x)\mathrm{d}\lambda(x),
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
which is written $2\lambda(f)$ in original notion. But then by linearity of the Lebesgue measure, for any $f\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})\subset L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, the class of simple functions, it must also be that
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        \mathbb{E}_0\int_0^{\tau_0}f(X_t)\mathrm{d}t&=\sum_{j}\mathbb{E}_0\int_0^{\tau_0}\xi_j{1}_{A_j}(x)\mathrm{d}t\\
        &=2\sum_{j}\xi_j\int_{\mathbb{R}}{1}_{A_j}(x)\mathrm{d}\lambda(x)=2\lambda(f).
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
Hence, using the standard machinery along with integrability of $f$ shows that for any $f,g\in L^1(\lambda)$
\begin{equation}\label{eq:sm}
    \mathbb{E}_0\int_0^{\tau_0}f(X_t)\mathrm{d}t=2\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)\mathrm{d}\lambda(x).
\end{equation}
Now for any $T\geq 0$, define $K(T)=\max\{n\geq 0:\tau_0^n\leq T\}$. If $n=1$, then if $\inf\{t\geq 0:X_t=1\}\leq T$, then there exists $0\leq t_1\leq t_2\leq T$ so that $X_{t_1}=1$ and $X_{t_2}=0$, and in general, for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, if $\tau_0^n\leq T$, then there exists a sequence of strictly increasing times $(t_j)_{j=1,...,2n}$ such that $(X_{t_j})_{j=1,...,2n}=({1}\{j=0\mod 2\})_{j=1,...,2n}$, that is to say, with $U_T([0,1], (t_j)_{j=1,...,2n})$ the upcrossings on $[0,T]$ for the discrete time process $(X_t)_{t=t_1,...,t_{2n}}$, it holds true that $U_{\tau_1^n}([0,1],(t_j)_{j=1,...,2n})=n$. Now write $\mathcal{A}(n)=(t_j)_{j=1,...,2n}$, and observe that for any $t_j\in\mathcal{A}(n)$ with $j=1\mod 2$, by the symmetry property of the Brownian motion and the fact that the semigroup is strong Markov, it must be that $\inf\{t\geq \tau_1^{n}:X_t=0\}\sim\inf\{t\geq\tau_1^{n}:X_t=2\}$, and so, we know that $\mathbb{E}{1}\{\tau_0^n\leq t\}=\mathbb{E}{1}\{\inf\{t\geq 0:X_t=2n\}\leq t\}$ for all $t\geq 0$.
Now by the properties of the Brownian motion, if $\theta:C[0,\infty)\to C[0,\infty)$ denotes the shift map for the Brownian motion, then it is not too difficult to verify that $W_{\tau_0^n+t}\circ\theta_{\tau_0^n}\sim W_t$, that is, if the Brownian motion hits zero, then shifting it back to the origin creates a new Brownian motion. And so, from a probabilistic point of view, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $f(X_{\tau_0^n+t}\circ\theta_{\tau_0^n})\sim f(X_t)$. That is to say, the set of random variables $Y^n=\int_{\tau_0^{n-1}}^{\tau_0^n}f(X_t)\mathrm{d}t$ defines an identically distributed sequence of random variables for all $f\in L^1(\lambda)$. Now for a fixed $T>0$ with $n=K(T)$
\begin{equation}\label{eq:lln}
    \begin{split}
        K(T)^{-1}\int_0^{\tau_0^n}f(X_t)\mathrm{d}t&=\sum_{m=2}^n\frac{1}{n}\int_{\tau_0^{m-1}}^{\tau_0^m}f(X_t)\mathrm{d}t\xrightarrow{T\to\infty}\mathbb{E}_0\int_0^{\tau_0}f(X_t)\mathrm{d}t,
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
by virtue of the law of large numbers, which by the result above shows that $\lim_{T\to\infty}K(T)^{-1}\int_0^{\tau_0^n}f(X_t)\mathrm{d}t=2\lambda(f)$. Clearly, this then implies that $\lim_{T\to\infty}\int_0^{\tau_0^n}f(X_t)\mathrm{d}t/\int_0^{\tau_0^n}g(X_t)\mathrm{d}t=\lambda(f)/\lambda(g)$ provided $|\lambda(g)|>0$. Now in the equation above, we actually truncated the left sum, as it in full is written $K(T)^{-1}\int_0^{\tau_0^n}f(X_t)\mathrm{d}t+K(T)^{-1}\int_{\tau_0^n}^Tf(X_t)\mathrm{d}t$, but $\int_{\tau_0^n}^Tf(X_t)\mathrm{d}t<\infty$, and so dividing by $n$ shows that it converges to zero, completing the proof.
Indeed, the proof misses some technical details, but I wanted to make sure that the logic checks out before perfecting the proof by filling in the detail. I am mostly not sure about the claim regarding the law of large numbers. I know that $\mathbb{E}_0\int_0^{\tau_0}f(X_t)\mathrm{d}t=2\lambda(f)$, and so I can only image that the law of large numbers argument is required, but it feels wrong the way I have done it so far. I would think that perhaps the random variables $Y^n$, in addition to being identically distributed, would also be independent, and intuition says that they do, but I have no idea how to prove or disprove that claim.
Any help is very appreciated!
